# error come out at the time of image upload using Fine Uploader 5.16.2

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce

When i try to upload image using fine Uploader,i got error message as per snapshot attached. please tell me how to solved this error. I don't know how to resolved this error. i have try myself but i cant found. please help me to solve this error.

[image: error log of console]

Comment: Which version 4.1?

Comment: It seems you should check the actual response in the network tab. There seems to be some html on it.

Comment: @sina_Islam yes this is 4.1 vesion

Comment: @MarcoRegueira i have checked into network tab but i cant get any think solution from their.

Comment: Well, instead of checking the javascript, you need to determine the reason for the error in the server. For that you need to check what you're sending and receiving (the network tab will help) and what happens in the server (the error log in nop commerce to start with)

Comment: @MarcoRegueira image uploading working fine in almost time but in some time i got this error.